# How to setup Angular 2, Node (Hapi.js) and TypeScript in one project?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, hapi.js, typescript-typings

I would like to setup Angular 2 (TypeScript) and Node (Hapi.js with TypeScript) project. Can you give me step by step tutorial how to organize and setup my project?

**I know how to setup Angular 2 (TypeScript) in one and Node (Hapi.js and TypeScript) in other project but I have problems when I merge client and server side in one project. I have problems with multiple typings, loading modules, different tsconfigs, loading libs on web page, folder structure, ...**

As I understand SystemJS and Webpack are the same thing and they are used to prepare JS files for using it on web page. Is that correct and if it is which one would you choose (also that one provide in tutorial for project setup)?

Also I would like to know is it useful to use Gulp or Grunt and where would be place in project setup for those technologies?

To summarize which technologies stack would be best to choose for developing Angular 2 and Node (Hapi.js) apps using TypeScript and how to setup them?